# how to set slideToggle open div just on the first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sky94132003/gbptvmnk/

I create a comment function for my site

there is a button for the user click to reply a comment.

onclick function will be do something

```
1. open slideToggle
2. animate scrollTop to the comment box (textarea)
3. animate backgroundColor (notic user where comment.)


$(function() {
    $( ".reply_video" ).click(function() {
      $(".comment_reply_video").slideToggle( "fast" );
         $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop:$('.comment_reply_video').offset().top-90}, 800);
          $(".comment_reply_video").animate({
                backgroundColor: '#CCC'
          }, 800 );      
         setTimeout(function() {
                $(".comment_reply_video").animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#FFF'
              }, 1200 );
         }, 1500); 

      $(".r_all").focus();
    });
});
```

But the user click the first will be open the slideToggle.

how can I set the just the first will be active slideToggle function?

If opened. onclick just to do

```
2.animate scrollTop to the comment box (textarea)    
3.animate backgroundColor (notic user where comment.)
```

and dont close the slideToggle

Comment: How about just replacing `slideToggle` with `slideDown`, or am I missing something ?

Comment: thanks adeneo. just that. thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your code.

Added :  `$(".reply_video").off("click")` to the toggle event.

```
$( ".reply_video" ).click(function() {
  $(".comment_reply_video").slideToggle( "fast" );
     $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop:$('.comment_reply_video').offset().top-90}, 800);
      $(".comment_reply_video").animate({
            backgroundColor: '#CCC'
      }, 800 );      
     setTimeout(function() {
            $(".comment_reply_video").animate({
                backgroundColor: '#FFF'
          }, 1200 );
     }, 1500); 
    $(".reply_video").off("click");
  $(".r_all").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace .click with .one('click', ...
Example:

```
 $( ".reply_video" ).one('click',function() { ... });
```

However, if you also want secondary functionality, use the .is(':visible') function.

Example:
(Inside click event)

```
$( ".reply_video" ).click(function() {
    if (!$(".comment_reply_video").is(":visible")) {
  $(".comment_reply_video").slideToggle( "fast" );
     $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop:$('.comment_reply_video').offset().top-90}, 800);
      $(".comment_reply_video").animate({
            backgroundColor: '#CCC'
      }, 800 );      
     setTimeout(function() {
            $(".comment_reply_video").animate({
                backgroundColor: '#FFF'
          }, 1200 );
     }, 1500); 
    }

  $(".r_all").focus();
});
```